# Reading CSV File in PHP and removing spaces and special character also storing it in db

Tags: php

I have wrote this code in php. it is reading and storing data in db from a simple csv file.
but when i try to read a csv file with special character blank spaces and multiple commas it is not reading the value

```
<?php
include_once 'connection.php';
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if($_FILES['csv_data']['name']){

        $arrFileName = explode('.',$_FILES['csv_data']['name']);
        if($arrFileName[1] == 'csv'){
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_data']['tmp_name'], "r");

            while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                echo $arrFileName;

                 $hr = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[1]);
                $min = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[2]);
                $day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[3]);
                $month = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[4]);
                $year = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[5]);
                $castno = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[14]);
                $si = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[27]);
                $su = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[30]);
                $mng = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[33]);
                $phos = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$data[36]);
                $import="INSERT into hm(hr,min,day,month,year,castno,si,su,mng,phos) values('$hr','$min','$day','$month','$year','$castno','$si','$su','$mng','$phos')";
                mysqli_query($conn,$import);
            }

            fclose($handle);
            print "Import done";
        }
    }
}
```

?>

Comment: Can you give an example of the CSV file where it doesn't work (preferably a few lines rather than a whole file).

Comment: NA,16,53,04,08,18,HMSMS_CM,ARL     ,        ,        ,1,1,0,0,9532/3 T5 S1,,,,,,,,,,4,Si,,1.23,S,,0.046,Mn,(,0.139,P,,0.122,

Comment: I've tried reading that data and it seems to read OK, when you say *not reading* do you mean a record isn't created or the fields are in the wrong place?  If you try `print_r($data);` in the loop, does this record display?  Try with a file just containing this one row.

Answer (score 0):

I do this quite a bit in my day to day and without a doubt if you are hosting this on a linux box and have the ability to access sed and tr on the machine the easiest thing to do will be:

```
// clean bad characters that are not detected by the tr below
shell_exec("sed -i '{s/\\x0C/ /g; s/\\x1A/ /g; s/\\xA0/ /g; s/\\x00/ /g;}' $filePath");

// clean the tmp file and place the clean file back in the original file path
shell_exec("tr '\\200-\\377' ' ' < $filePath > $cleanFilePath");

// remove any blank/empty lines in the file
shell_exec("sed -i '/^$/d' $cleanFilePath");
```

This looks for hex characters and if they are invalid (match or are outside of certain ranges) it removes them from the file. `tr` doesn't as far as I know have an in place ability (it's been quite a while since i've looked) and for that reason you end up outputing the result into `$cleanFilePath` which can be whatever/where ever you want. This also a great deal faster than an implementation in PHP (these tools are build for large text files, aka csv files) so why not leverage them.

In my day job we process files with 2 million rows in a few seconds which is a huge boost. You can do this in PHP but from my experience (my mistake of initially implementing this in PHP) I would steer clear of that solution as it is much more complex and a great deal slower.

Answer (score 0):

I'd perhaps suggest that you refactor the above to use a prepared statement - it will be more robust and more efficient, especially if at any point a non trusted user is able to POST data.

```
<?php

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty( $_POST['submit'] ) && !empty( $_FILES['csv_data'] ) ){
        try{

            include_once 'connection.php';

            /* the sql query with placeholders ~ 10 columns, 10 placeholders */
            $sql='insert into `hm` ( `hr`,`min`,`day`,`month`,`year`,`castno`,`si`,`su`,`mng`,`phos` ) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);';

            /* Get various properties of the uploaded file */
            $obj=(object)$_FILES['csv_data'];
            $ext=strtolower( pathinfo( $obj->name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION ) );
            $name=$obj->name;
            $tmp=$obj->tmp_name;
            $err=$obj->error;

            /* If there are no errors and the file is a .csv proceed */
            if( $err== 0 && $ext=='csv' ){

                printf('Begin importing %s',$name);

                /* create the prepared statement object - exit if it fails */
                $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
                if( !$stmt )throw new Exception('Failed to prepare query');

                /* Not know if these should be integers or strings... */
                $stmt->bind_param( 'ssssssssss', $hr,$min,$day,$month,$year,$castno,$si,$su,$mng,$phos );

                /* read the csv file */
                $data = new SplFileObject( $tmp );
                $data->setFlags( SplFileObject::READ_CSV );

                /* process each line - create variables */
                foreach( $data as $i => $line ) {
                    list( $hr,$min,$day,$month,$year,$castno,$si,$su,$mng,$phos )=$line;

                    /* insert the record */
                    $stmt->execute();
                }

                $stmt->close();

                printf( '<br />Importing %d lines from %s complete', $i, $name );
            }
        }catch( Exception $e ){
            exit( $e->getMessage() );
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: but it is not reading the desired values in the format. as the CSV File data is like. NA,16,53,04,08,18,HMSMS_CM,ARL , , ,1,1,0,0,9532/3 T5 S1,,,,,,,,,,4,Si,,1.23,S,,0.046,Mn,(,0.139,P,,0.122,

Comment: Can you create a pastebin paste of the data - it is hard to understand the format from the given example here